# Cover Whole Screen with Plotly Chart on Dash App

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

Currently when I use Plotly with Dash there's a large blank space under the graph on the rest of the web app, however when I use fig.show() method the chart takes up the whole screen as intended.

The Two images below should provide all the information. I would like my dash app (bottom pic) to look taller as in the simple plotly version (top pic) picture.[[image: Dash app]][image: Simple Plotly figure]

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px  # (version 4.7.0 or higher)
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from dash import Dash, dcc, html, Input, Output  # pip install dash (version 2.0.0 or higher)
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import yfinance as yf
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots






app = Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.LUX])

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# App layout
app.layout = html.Div(style={
                             'height':'100vh',
                             'padding': 10
                             }, children=[

#    html.H1("MarketFeel", style={'text-align': 'center'}),
#    html.H3("Unlock the Sentiment of the Markets", style={'text-align': 'center'}),

    dcc.Dropdown(id="slct_Market",
                 options=[
                     {"label": "Bitcoin", "value": "BTCSentiment.csv"},
                     {"label": "Ethereum", "value": "ETHSentiment.csv"},
                     {"label": "Dogecoin", "value": "DOGESentiment.csv"},
                     {"label": "Cardano", "value": "ADASentiment.csv"},
                     {"label": "Kucoin", "value": "KCSSentiment.csv"},
                     {"label": "Vechain", "value": "VETSentiment.csv"},
                     {"label": "AMC", "value": "AMCSentiment.csv"},
                     {"label": "Amazon", "value": "AMZNSentiment.csv"},
                     {"label": "Dash", "value": "DASHSentiment.csv"},
                     {"label": "Facebook", "value": "FBSentiment.csv"},
                     {"label": "Litecoin", "value": "LTCSentiment.csv"},
                     {"label": "Tesla", "value": "TSLASentiment.csv"},
                     {"label": "Ripple", "value": "XRPSentiment.csv"},

                 ],
                 multi=False,
                 value="BTCSentiment.csv",
                 style={'width': "40%"}
                 ),

    dcc.Dropdown(id="my-dpdn2",
                 multi=True,
                 options=[
                     {"label": "Fear", "value": "Fear"},
                     {"label": "Anger", "value": "Anger"},
                     {"label": "Anticipation", "value": "Anticipation"},
                     {"label": "Trust", "value": "Trust"},
                     {"label": "Surprise", "value": "Surprise"},
                     {"label": "Sadness", "value": "Sadness"},
                     {"label": "Disgust", "value": "Disgust"},
                     {"label": "Joy", "value": "Joy"}],

                 value=["Fear"],
                 ),

    html.Div(id='output_container', children=[]),
    html.Br(),

    dcc.Graph(id='my_sentiment_chart', figure={}, )

])


# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Connect the Plotly graphs with Dash Components
@app.callback(
    [Output(component_id='output_container', component_property='children'),
     Output(component_id='my_sentiment_chart', component_property='figure')],
    [Input(component_id='slct_Market', component_property='value'),
     Input(component_id='my-dpdn2', component_property='value')]
)
# Section updates graph shown depending on what options user selects from above drop down menus
def update_graph(mkt_selected, option_slctd):
#    print(option_slctd[0])
    df = pd.read_csv(mkt_selected)
    df.reset_index(inplace=True)

    container = "The Emotion chosen by user was: {}".format(option_slctd)
    container1 = ""

    dff = df.copy()


    # Plotly Express

    myDict = {"BTCSentiment.csv": 'Bitcoin',
              "DOGESentiment.csv": 'Dogecoin',
              "ETHSentiment.csv": 'Ethereum',
              "ADASentiment.csv": 'Cardano',
              "KCSSentiment.csv": 'Kucoin',
              "VETSentiment.csv": 'Vechain',

              }

    priceDict = {"BTCSentiment.csv": 'BTC-USD',
                 "DOGESentiment.csv": 'DOGE-USD',
                 "ETHSentiment.csv": 'ETH-USD',
                 "ADASentiment.csv": 'ADA-USD',
                 "KCSSentiment.csv": 'Kucoin',
                 "VETSentiment.csv": 'VET-USD',
                 "AMCSentiment.csv": 'AMC',
                 "DASHSentiment.csv": 'DASH-USD',
                 "FBSentiment.csv": 'FB',
                 "LTCSentiment.csv": 'LTC-USD',
                 "TSLASentiment.csv": 'TSLA',
                 "XRPSentiment.csv": 'XRP-USD'
                 }


    startDate = dff['Date'][1]
    endDate = dff['Date'].iloc[-1]

    data = yf.download(priceDict[mkt_selected], start=startDate, 
         end=endDate).reset_index().pipe \
        (lambda d: d.rename(columns={c: c.lower()
        if c != "Date" else "datetime" for c in d.columns}))

    fig = make_subplots(specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}]])



    if len(option_slctd) != 0:
        for item in option_slctd:
            fig.add_trace(go.Line(name=item, x=dff['Date'], y=dff[item]),
                          secondary_y=True)

        fig.add_trace(go.Candlestick(name="Price",
                                     x=data['datetime'],
                                     open=data['open'],
                                     high=data['high'],
                                     low=data['low'],
                                     close=data['close'],
                                     line=dict(width=1)),
                      secondary_y=False)

        fig.update_yaxes(title_text="Emotion Level (%)", secondary_y=True)


    else:
        fig.add_trace(go.Candlestick(name="Price",
                                     x=data['datetime'],
                                     open=data['open'],
                                     high=data['high'],
                                     low=data['low'],
                                     close=data['close'],
                                     line=dict(width=1)),
                      secondary_y=False)
        fig.update_yaxes(title_text="Price", secondary_y=False)


    fig.update_yaxes(title_text="Price", secondary_y=False)
    fig.update_traces(line_color="Blue", selector=dict(type='Line'))



    fig.update_layout(
        autosize=True,

    )

    fig.update_xaxes(rangeslider_visible=True)

    config = dict({'scrollZoom': True})


    return container1,fig
```

Comment: I find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46287189/how-can-i-change-the-size-of-my-dash-graph) to be very helpful

Comment: Thank you @r-beginners, solved the problem!!

Answer (score 2):

To remove/reduce the blank area around your graph you can use:

```
fig.update_layout(
   margin=dict(l=0, r=0, t=0, b=0)
)
```

Comment: Does not help, still not using full windows height