# Resize plotly figure in Dash to full size of the window

Tags: image, plotly

Using the [documentation](https://plotly.com/python/3d-surface-plots/) of `plotly.Surface` and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65004010/7959614) I have the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
from dash import Dash, html, dcc
import plotly.graph_objects as go

app = Dash(__name__)

z_data = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/api_docs/mt_bruno_elevation.csv')


fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Surface(z=z_data.values, colorscale='Greens')])
fig.update_traces(showscale=False)
fig.update_xaxes(domain=(0, 1))
fig.update_yaxes(domain=(0, 1))

app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    dcc.Graph(
        id='green',
        figure=fig,
        style={'width': '100vh', 'height': '100vh'}
    )
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

The goal is to stretch the figure along the horizontal axis / across the whole window. However, this doesn't happen because the output looks as follows:

[image]

How do I make sure the image fills the whole page along the x-axis?