# Preserve scales of a plotly figure using dash

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I want to know how to preserve the plotly figure layout using dash.
Here's how it looks without dash:
[image]

And this is how it looks while using Dash: [image]

I'm using Dash because I want to make the port number consistent (e.g 8050).

This is my code:

```
# Show plot
# fig.show()

# Port number for the web server
port_number = 8050

# Initialize a Dash app
app = dash.Dash(__name__)

# Defining the layout
app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Graph(figure=fig)
])

# Run the app on the specified port
app.run_server(port=port_number)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `fig.show()` the default width and height are both 100%, but when using a Dash Graph, the figure height will be fixed to 450px by default, and for some obscure reason setting `height: 100%` via the graph `style` property doesn't work. Though, if we set `'height': '95vh'` it works (not 100vh to prevent a vertical scrollbar) :

```py
dcc.Graph(figure=fig, style={'width': '100%', 'height': '95vh'})
```

NB. The problem with `'width' : '90vh'` is that the graph won't be responsive to window width change.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the viewport sizing of the Graph object?

```
dcc.Graph(figure = fig, style = {'width' : '90vh', 'height' : '90vh'})
```

It seems the graph will now take up 90% of the browser page.

Ref: [How can I change the size of my Dash Graph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46287189/how-can-i-change-the-size-of-my-dash-graph)